# Protein Isolation from mammalian cells

Tags: molecular-biology

What non-SDS buffer can I use to isolate protein from mammalian cells? The protein is intended for testing electron transport chain complexes.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer - you will need to use a nonionic detergent. These will dissolve lipid membranes but leave most protein complexes intact, and many proteins in active form.

However [there are many of these available](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/life-science/biochemicals/biochemical-products.html?TablePage=14572924) and finding the right one for a particular job is a black art.

The usual approach is to start off with something widely-used and not too expensive like Triton X-100. Detergents with glycoside head groups are also widely-used but tend towards the expensive.